# Ignoring empty elements with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML workflow where we're building an output document from an XML source but some of the data elements are empty but still appearing in the output. The problem is that we are generating paragraph returns and spacing based on the final output.

In some cases the data contains `<address1>` and `<address2>` elements. When it does we want it to look like this (A):

```
<address1>123 Main Str</address1><xsl:text> </xsl:text><zip>60060</zip>
```

When does not have data in the `<address2>` element, we want it to appear this way (B):

```
<address1>123 Main Str</address1> <hours>M-F 9:00am - 5:00pm</hours><xsl:text> 
</xsl:text><address2>PO Box 123</address2> <zip>60060</zip>
```

BUT, the XML contains EMPTY data elements such as `<address2></address2>` so we end up with the following situation (C):

```
<address1>123 Main Str</address1> <hours>M-F 9:00am - 5:00pm</hours><xsl:text> 
</xsl:text><address2/><xsl:text> </xsl:text><zip>60060</zip>
```

Our XSL works fine until it hits an empty element. I'm sure there's a way to create option A even when there is an empty element. I tried using `<xsl:if test="string-length(node) != 0">` but I couldn't get it to work. I want to get rid of the empty `<address2/>` elements and move the `<zip>` element up to the previous line.

Here is my current XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- DWXMLSource="IndividualBanks_2011 final.xml" -->
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

<Root>
<Story><xsl:apply-templates select="Root"/></Story>
</Root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="BankName | Address1 | Hours | Established | RoutingNbr | CO/CityOfficePhone | CO/CityOfficeAddress2 "><xsl:element name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="BK">
<xsl:apply-templates select="BankName"/><xsl:text>  </xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="Established"/>    <xsl:text>    </xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="RoutingNbr"/><xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
<xsl:apply-templates select="OfficeOfLabel"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Address1"/><xsl:text>  </xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="Hours"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Address2"/><xsl:apply-templates select="Zip"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Address2"><xsl:text>
</xsl:text><Address2><xsl:value-of select="."/></Address2><xsl:text>    </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Zip">
<Zip><xsl:value-of select="."/></Zip><xsl:text>
</xsl:text></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the XML data source:

```
<Root><BK><BankName>Ames National Corporation</BankName><Established>Est. 1975</Established><RoutingNbr>8020-0135-0</RoutingNbr><Address1>405 5th Street</Address1><Hours>Hrs: M-F 8-5</Hours><Address2></Address2>  <Zip>50010</Zip><Fax>FAX: (515) 663-3033</Fax><Phone>(515) 232-6251</Phone><WebURL>Web: www.amesnational.com</WebURL><MultiBankLabel>Please see Multi-Bank Holding Companies section</MultiBankLabel>
</BK>
<BK><BankName>Bank of the West</BankName><Address1>525 Main</Address1><Zip>50010-6008</Zip><Fax>FAX: (515) 232-3791</Fax><Phone>(515) 232-8664</Phone><OfficeOfLabel>Office of Bank of the West, West Des Moines</OfficeOfLabel>
<EH><Employee>Michael Sondall, BM</Employee></EH>
</BK>
<BK><BankName>Bankers Trust Company</BankName><Address1>1510 Buckeye </Address1><Zip>50010</Zip><Phone>(515) 233-4424</Phone><WebURL>Web: www.bankerstrust.com</WebURL><OfficeOfLabel>Office of Bankers Trust Company, Des Moines</OfficeOfLabel>
<EH><Employee>John Russell, VP</Employee></EH>
</BK>
<BK><BankName>Exchange State Bank</BankName><RoutingNbr>0739-0950-7</RoutingNbr><Address1>823 Wheeler, Ste 32</Address1><Zip>50010</Zip><Fax>FAX: (515) 232-5068</Fax><Phone>(515) 232-5060</Phone><Email>e-Mail: ames@esb1.com</Email><OfficeOfLabel>Office of Exchange State Bank, Collins</OfficeOfLabel>
<EH><Employee>Allison Appel, VP, CPA</Employee></EH><EH><Employee>Christine Heintz, AVP</Employee></EH>
</BK>
<BK><BankName>First American Bank</BankName><Established>Est. 1956</Established><RoutingNbr>0739-0080-7</RoutingNbr><Address1>1530 S Duff Avenue, Ste 1</Address1><Hours>Hrs: M-TH 9-5 SAT 8-12</Hours><Address2>    </Address2><Zip>50010</Zip><Fax>FAX: (515) 956-3160</Fax><Phone>(515) 233-2033</Phone><WebURL>Web: </WebURL>    <OfficeOfLabel>Office of First American Bank, Fort Dodge</OfficeOfLabel>
<EH><Employee>Steve Goodhue, Reg Pres</Employee></EH>
</BK></Root>
```

Comment: Just wondering - are (A) and (B) swapped? Also, your XML data source is not well-formed (should end with `</Root>` rather than `</root>`).

Comment: Moreover, I'm not sure why for you, the result with empty `<address2>` elements includes `<xsl:text>` elements - it doesn't for me. Please take care of proper casing. Xml is case-sensitive, so `<address2>` (as in your code snippets) is not the same as `<Address2>` (as in your complete Xml documents).

Comment: Sorry for the tiny errors, I extracted the XML from a larger file for  simplicity and added the parent tags back and introduced some typos. The actual XML is well-formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach with the `string-length` function wasn't bad, but maybe you inserted it in the wrong place?

The `<Zip>` element is on the previous line for me when I replace your XSLT line

```
<xsl:template match="Address2"><xsl:text>
```

with

```
<xsl:template match="Address2[string-length() != 0]"><xsl:text>
```

Does that do what you want? I'm not quite sure whether you also want to skip the `<Hours>` if there's no `<Address2>` specified.

**Update:** In order to apply a different ordering to the elements if `<Address2>` is empty, use an `<xsl:choose>` structure with a similar condition as above:

```
<xsl:template match="BK">
<xsl:apply-templates select="BankName"/><xsl:text>  </xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="Established"/>    <xsl:text>    </xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="RoutingNbr"/><xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
<xsl:apply-templates select="OfficeOfLabel"/>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="string-length(Address2) != 0">
<xsl:apply-templates select="Address1"/><xsl:text>  </xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="Hours"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Address2"/><xsl:apply-templates select="Zip"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Address1"/><xsl:text>   </xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="Zip"/><xsl:text>  </xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="Hours"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

You can then completely skip the template for `<Address2>`.

Comment: That worked like a champ. Great. It's like they say about restaurants, location, location, location....

On a related topic, my boss wants the zip to appear BETWEEN `<Address1>` and `<Hours>` if the `<Address2>` element is empty. Any suggestions how we set that condition up? Right now, it appears AFTER `<Hours>`.

Comment: @JimMaivald: In your template starting with `<xsl:template match="BankName | Address1 | Hours | Established | RoutingNbr | CO/CityOfficePhone | CO/CityOfficeAddress2 ">`, you insert various elements (with `xsl:apply-templates>`) in a fixed order. One of these elements is the `<Zip>` element. Try to use `<xsl:if>` or `<xsl:choose>` there to check whether `<Address2>` is empty, and if so, insert the elements in a different order. Let me know if this information is insufficient.

Comment: I've never had luck with the xsl:if function. Do I create one template if the address2 is there, and then nest the other one if address2 is missing in the "otherwise" section?

Also, should I drop the `<address1>` and `<zip>` elements from the "match" section noted above if they are listed in the "xsl:if" statement?

Comment: @ORMapper What's the syntax for the "XSL:if" or "XSL:Choose" to test if `<address2>` is present and NOT empty? Is it the same as the one you suggested for "match" above?

Comment: @ORMapper If `<Hours>` is present, it should appear after `<zip>` when `<Address2>` is empty or missing, such as:

`<address1>123 Main Str</address1> <zip>60060</zip> <hours>M-F 9:00am - 5:00pm</hours>`

Comment: Let me know if I should ask this as a separate question. It sounds like it's getting a little complicated.

Comment: @JimMaivald: I've extended my answer to cover that reordering with an `<xsl:choose>` structure.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be numerous inconsistencies in the information you have given us, but the simple solution is to add a template rule:

```
<xsl:template match="address2[not(child::node())]"/>
```

Comment: Sorry about the small errors. The XML was actually well-formed but I inserted only a portion of it to save space. Thanks for the reply